# differential form: a question in Novikov's book

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms

I met a problem when reading the book of Novikov et al. "Modern geometry, vol 1".

In page 200 of the book (GTM 93, English version), they say for 2-form $F$,
$$
(F\wedge F)_{0123}=-{1\over 2}\epsilon^{ijkl}F_{ij}F_{kl} 
$$

However I cannot get the coefficients or signs...

The following is my calculation:

Using the definition of coefficient of differential form:
$$
F=\sum_{i<j}F_{ij} \mathrm{d}x^i \wedge \mathrm{d}x^j.
$$
Hence
\begin{align}
F\wedge F&=(\sum_{i<j}F_{ij} \mathrm{d}x^i \wedge \mathrm{d}x^j)\wedge (\sum_{k<l}F_{kl} \mathrm{d}x^k \wedge \mathrm{d}x^l)\\
&=\sum_{i<j}\sum_{k<l}F_{ij}F_{kl} \mathrm{d}x^i \wedge \mathrm{d}x^j\wedge  \mathrm{d}x^k \wedge \mathrm{d}x^l\\
&= \sum_{i<j}\sum_{k<l}F_{ij}F_{kl}\epsilon^{ijkl} \mathrm{d}x^0 \wedge \mathrm{d}x^1\wedge  \mathrm{d}x^2 \wedge \mathrm{d}x^3\\&
=\frac{1}{4}F_{ij}F_{kl}\epsilon^{ijkl} \mathrm{d}x^0 \wedge \mathrm{d}x^1\wedge  \mathrm{d}x^2 \wedge \mathrm{d}x^3
\end{align}

Again by definition of differential form,
$$
F\wedge F=(F\wedge F)_{0123}\mathrm{d}x^0 \wedge \mathrm{d}x^1\wedge  \mathrm{d}x^2 \wedge \mathrm{d}x^3.
$$

This implies 
$$
(F\wedge F)_{0123}=\frac{1}{4}F_{ij}F_{kl}\epsilon^{ijkl}.
$$

I am not sure where is the problem. The book usually uses calculation with $sgn(\sigma)$, while I use the representation under basis here.

I get even more confused using formulas with $sgn(\sigma)$...

Thanks a lot for your help!

(By the way, as a student majoring in Applied mathematics, I really like these Russian books, with wonderful explanations of concrete calculation and applications in physics and mechanics!)

Comment: What you've written seems consistent modulo the statement from the text with the $-1/2$. I wonder, what is the definition of $F_{ij}$ in the text?

Comment: James, indeed the background is 4-dimensional Minkowski space. $F_{ij}$ is defined to be components of 2-form F under coordinates $\{x^k\}$. It corresponds to a skew-symmetric matrix. In some sense $F=\sum_{i<j}F_{ij}\mathrm{d}x^i \wedge \mathrm{d}x^j$ can be viewed as a definition of $F_{ij}$?

Comment: That is one possible definition, but, if they write $F = F_{ij}dx^i \wedge dx^j$ then do you agree with their definition? I wish I had the book... on my wishlist...

Comment: I also tried this. But if we remove "i<j", then repeat the procedure, we just remove $\frac{1}{4}$ and get $$F_{ij}F_{kl}\epsilon^{ijkl}?$$